# Kerberos authentication works in IE, not Chrome: 401 error

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, kerberos, spn

I've set up my Internet Explorer so that it can pass Active Directory login credentials using Local Intranet settings to Kerberos.  As far as I know, Chrome just copies these settings from IE.  I am however getting 401 errors when making XHR request in Chrome and not IE.  When I open the request in a new tab in Chrome, there is no errors, only during the AJAX request via AngularJS.

Is there anything I can set in Chrome to amend this?  I rather not continue doing dev work on IE as I prefer the dev tool set/console in Chrome much more.

Comment: Hi; If we've answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any.

Comment: In fiddler I can see when I open the request in new tab in chrome, it gets a 401 using Authentication: Basic, and silently retries again with a Authentication: Negotiate which is when it comes back successfully.

Comment: I've fixed it, turns out the original angularjs http had a default header set to "Basic " I removed this and now it works on Chrome, not sure why this never caused an issue with IE.

Comment: Great job!  Please turn your comment above into an answer and self-accept.  It will then mark itself in Green and advertise itself as a community solution.  You'll get more credit that way too.